# Check if the parameters passed to a method is one of the constants defined in a class?

Tags: php, class, oop, constants, type-hinting

I am seeking a way to know if the parameters passed to a method is a constant defined in a specific class. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    const CONSTANT = 4;
    const ANOTHER_CONSTANT = 5;

    public function aMethod ($a_CONSTANT) {
        // function code
   } 
 } 

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->aMethod(MyClass::CONSTANT); // Fine
$myClass->aMethod(MyClass::ANOTHER_CONSTANT) ; // Still okay
$myClass->aMethod(4); // Not okay
$myClass->aMethod(OtherClass::VALUE); // No way
```

In the above code, first two calls to `aMethod` are acceptable but I want the parser to give an error while the third and fourth call to `aMethod` happens, since the value passed to `aMethod` is not a constant of a particular class (`MyClass`, in this case). Is there a syntax to typehint the parameter in `aMethod` to achieve what I want?

Comment: No. You need to manually check the passed value against those constants. A constant is just a container for a value. When you pass a constant to a method, it's only the value that's getting passed. The class has no clue, nor should it, what that value came from in the outer scope. It's all about the actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass "a constant", you're not passing the constant itself, you're passing its value. `MyClass::CONSTANT` and `4` are exactly synonymous. There is no difference between them you could detect. In fact, the compiler replaces all mentions of "`MyClass::CONSTANT`" with `4` at compile time. That's what constants are.

Comment: Hey thanks! I kinda wanted to restrict this to just constants and no hardcoded value so that when constants change, the new value is automatically reflected to all the places it was used.

Comment: Yes, a worthy cause, but alas there's nothing in the language that would help you. Maybe some style checker exists that could parse some comment annotations for this purpose, but I don't know.

Comment: Yes! If I define a class `OtherClass` with a constant, say `OC_CONSTANT` which stores value 4 or 5 then in the above code, I can call `aMethod` like this: `$myClass->aMethod(OtherClass::OC_CONSTANT)` and it will work identical as it does when a constant from `MyClass` is passed.